# No error in code but when you debug, I get an error (Eclipse Luna)

Tags: c, eclipse

My code works perfectly fine. But when I tried debugging it since it's my first time on Luna Eclipse and wanted to learn how the debugging process worked, it gives me an error saying

> *stopped,reason="end-stepping-range",frame={addr="0x00401479",func="main",args=[],file="..\src\Assignment1A.c",fullname="C:\Users\Sunghee\workspace2\Assignment1A\src\Assignment1A.c",line="37"},thread-id="1",stopped-threads="all"

I don't understand this, because it works perfectly fine when I run it. The error comes at my first if statement so at

```
printf("\n%d + %d =%d", num1, num2, ans);
if (num2 > 0) {
    printf("\n%d / %d = %d", num1, num2, num1 / num2);
    printf("\n%d %% %d = %d", num1, num2, num1 % num2);
}
else {
    printf("\n%d /%d is not allowed", num1, num2);
}
```

Can anyone tell me why? I already researched it but all the terms I don't understand kind of... didn't work for me :p THANKYOU!

It works in Eclipse when I run it. When I debug it line by line, the error occurs after that one line stated above.
The full code:

## include

## include

int main()
{
    int num1;       //First number to be input by user
    int num2;       //Second number to be input by user
    int ans;       //Variable to store math result

```
setbuf(stdout, 0);

printf("Please enter the first integer:\n");
scanf("%d", &num1);

printf("Please enter the second integer:\n");
scanf("%d", &num2);

ans = num1 + num2;
printf("\n%d + %d =%d", num1, num2, ans);
if (num2 > 0) {
    printf("\n%d / %d = %d", num1, num2, num1 / num2);
    printf("\n%d %% %d = %d", num1, num2, num1 % num2);
}

else {
    printf("\n%d /%d is not allowed", num1, num2);
    printf("\n%d %% %d is not allowed", num1, num2);
}

printf("\nThe average of %d and %d is %d", num1, num2, (num1+num2)/2);

return 0;
```

}

So if anyone can help, please do! As I said, there's no problem when I run it. But I want to know why there's an error when I debug it. For curiosity's sake :D

Comment: It works fine up til printf (...) But at f the error pops up in my consol and then I can't carry on debugging.

Comment: u mean your code work correctly except in eclise???

Comment: Please show the full code.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works perfectly fine for me. I think it has something to do with the way you have initialized your variables. Request you to share the entire code if possible.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) { 

    int num1 = 1,num2 =2,num3 = 3,ans =0;

    printf("\n%d + %d =%d", num1, num2, ans);
if (num2 > 0) {
    printf("\n%d / %d = %d", num1, num2, num1 / num2);
    printf("\n%d %% %d = %d", num1, num2, num1 % num2);
}
else {
    printf("\n%d /%d is not allowed", num1, num2);
}
    return 0;
}
```

Results

```
1 + 2 =0
1 / 2 = 0
1 % 2 = 1
```

Comment: My code actually worked fine. My question was to do with debugging- do you maybe know why I got that error that I did when I got to the if statement? I really want to know how this debugging thing works, and why it gave me an error when my code worked just fine :/